# How to optimize this mySQL query in terms of performance?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I optimize the follow query ?

```
select
hash,page,timestamp, count(*) as total
from behaviour
group by hash, page
having total > 2 AND timestamp >= Now() - interval 5 minute
```

Thank you

Comment: You can start by finding out why it's slow. No problem, anytime.

Answer (score 0):

This query it's not wrong.
Maybe with a bigger volume, you could have a problem with performance.
Try use  "WHERE CONDITIONS" always. (In your context, i don't know if is possible).
Another tip, is EXPLAIN on your query!
Use "explain" before your query. (explain select hash, timestamp, count(*)........).
In this way, you can discover how many results your query is returned.